# Hide all the elements with the same data attribute except the first ones

Tags: jquery

How to hide hide all the elements with the same data attribute and just display the first one?

```
<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter">
<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter">
<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter">
<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter">
<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter">

<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter-new">
<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter-new">
<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter-new">
<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter-old">
<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter-old">
```

I have elements with same data attribute which is `brand-filter` I want to hide all the elements except the first one base on their data attribute.

So the expected output will be

```
<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter">
<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter-new">
<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter-old">
```

Here is the script that I tried

```
$('.brand-filter').each(function() {
     var filter = $(this).data('filter-id');
     
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function.

You need have empty array called `existingData`

Check the the empty array if it `includes` filters on `.each` if the same filters already exist in the array then hide all the other remaining elements with same filter-ids except the ones in the array.

Run snippet to see it working.

```js
let existingData = []
$('.brand-filter').each(function() {
  let thisData = $(this).data('filter-id');
  if (!existingData.includes(thisData)) {
    existingData.push(thisData)
  } else {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter">
  1
</div>
<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter">
  2
</div>
<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter">
  3
</div>
<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter">
  4
</div>
<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter">
  5
</div>

<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter-new">
  New
</div>

<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter-new">
  New
</div>

<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter-new">
  New
</div>

<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter-old">
  Old
</div>

<div class="brand-filter" data-filter-id="brand-filter-old">
  Old
</div>
```